# Why do these queries work independently but not together?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 queries which I want to use on my firestore collection.

These 2 examples work:

```
database
  .collection('servicebonnen')
  .where('medewerker', '==', 'CEES')
```

and:

```
database
  .collection('servicebonnen')
  .where('date', '>', this.today)
  .where('date', '<', this.tomorrow)
```

Why doesn't combining these like so work?:

```
database
  .collection('servicebonnen')
  .where('medewerker', '==', 'CEES')
  .where('date', '>', this.today)
  .where('date', '<', this.tomorrow)
```

Comment: if you dont get an error, then you are getting no resuilts back. This would be because no data match these criteria

Comment: the 3rd query combines all three criteria with AND (ie ALL must match). So possibly no data match all criteria

Comment: Did you created composite index?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @hkchakladar It looks like that was the cause of the problem. Feel like posting it as an answer?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [firestore doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries):

> You can also chain multiple where() methods to create more specific queries (logical AND). However, to combine the equality operator (==) with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or array_contains), make sure to create a composite index.

So you need to create [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As @hkchakladar mentioned I needed to add a composite index to generate results for non default queries.